# Add toolbar to activity with a listView

Tags: java, android, layout, root

I'm trying to add a toolbar to my activity, which has only a list of elements as content. This is my code, but it doesn't works because it says that I'm using multiple root. How is it possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  style="@style/HeaderBar"
  app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
  android:elevation="4dp"/>
```

Comment: It seems the layout of the listview item. Not the activity layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put all that inside a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

In this example i use **RelativeLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:layout_below=""@+id/my_toolbar/>


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In case the toolbar is not a the top just add in the **Toolbar part** `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Comment: Why a RL or LL and not a ConstraintLayout for example?

Comment: I use RelativeLayout because with this one you can modify where to put Toolbar or whatever it is in any part of the activity

Answer (score 2):

Yes ... Android is right .

There can only be a single root layout . You can add a relative layout or linearlayout as root layout . root layout will wrap your textview and toolbar.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add the `Toolbar` in the `ListView` item layout.
You have to add the `Toolbar` in your `Activity` layout.

You should you something like:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <android.widget.ListView/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also you should use the [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) library and not the support libraries (for example [`androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar) instead of [`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar)) and a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of a [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView).